# What constraints will scale images together?

Tags: android, xml

I want to place and scale images together to fit within a view. They should all have the same aspect ratio and position relative to each other no matter the scale. There is one large image, the oval here, that should scale to fit its container. The rest of the images should scale at the same factor and be placed around it. I don't want to hard code any dp so that the images will scale to any size container. Notice the ball touching the oval:

[image]

I've implemented this behavior here using constraints, as follows:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="#ff8040"
    >

    <!-- horizontal guidelines -->
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/ovalTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0000" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/circleTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0608" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/circleBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1202" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/ovalBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0000" />

    <!-- vertical guidelines -->
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/ovalLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0000" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/circleLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7262" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/circleRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8337" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/ovalRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/oval"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ovalTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ovalBottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ovalLeft"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ovalRight"
        android:src="@drawable/oval" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/circleTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/circleBottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/circleLeft"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/circleRight"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the aspect ratio of the ConstraintLayout itself changes, however, it moves the circle relative to the oval:

[image]

The layout manager is constraining the oval while maintaining aspect ratio, but the smaller circle does not need to resize. I would like for the circle to resize with the oval and stay attached to it.

Everything would work if the large image was always consistently width-constrained or height-constrained, but I can't control that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get all of the images to scale with the largest images (like puzzle pieces) is to create a layout hard-coded to the same aspect ratio as the large image. The guidelines can be placed on this layout, and any small images attached to the guidelines will scale with the large image.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="40">

    <!-- 922x1715 matches the ratio of the large image.
    all guidelines are placed relative to that image -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="922:1715"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- horizontal guidelines -->

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/ovalTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0000" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/circleTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0608" />

        <!-- etc. -->
```